# Minimum amount of swaps needed so no number has two neighbours that are both greater..?

Tags: algorithm

The problem statement goes like this: Given a list of N < 500 000 distinct numbers, find the minimum number of swaps of adjacent elements required such that no number has two neighbours that are both greater. A number can only be swapped with a neighbour.
Hint given: Use a segment tree or a fenwick tree.

I don't really get the idea of how I should use a sum-tree to solve this problem.

Example inputs:

```
Input 1: 
5 (amount of elements in the list)
3 1 4 2 0

output 1: 1

input 2: 
6
4 5 2 0 1 3

output 2: 4
```

Comment: Apart from not being helped by the hint, what are your thoughts about the problem?

Comment: It should be easy to realise how a list that satisfies the requirement should look like (hint: bitonic). The remaining part is to find the closest such sequence.

Comment: I couldn't think of more than a brute force solution in O(N^2), where i basically check all the possibilities and choose the one with the fewest swaps... but that won't work for N > 10 000.

Comment: I can do it in O(n^2) by focusing on each lowest element in turn. The remaining trick is to pull off the same faster (or be fine with quadratic).

Comment: @JanDvorak The Fenwick tree is to keep the positions of the elements that haven't been moved yet up to date.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks. If that brings us faster runtime than linearithmic, please present your solution. If not, I have an O(n log n) solution in mind.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't know of an o(n log n)-time solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can do it in O(n log n) time and O(n) extra space. But first let's look at the quadratic solution I've hinted at earlier:

- initialize the result accumulator to 0
- while the input list has more than two elements

  - find the lowest element in the list
  - add its distance from the closer end of the list to the accumulator
  - remove the element from the list.
- output the accumulator.

Why does this work? First, Let's look at how a sequence that requires zero swap looks like. Since there are no duplicates, if the lowest element is anywhere but at either end, it is surrounded by two elements that are both greater, violating the requirement, thus the lowest element must be at one of the ends. Recurse into the subsequence that excludes this element. To bring a sequence into this state: at least as many swaps involving the lowest element as in the greedy algorithm are required to move the lowest element to one end, and since swaps involving the lowest element do not change the relative ordering of the rest, there is no penalty to reordering them to the front either.

Unfortunately, just implementing this with a list is quadratic. How do you make it faster? Have a finger tree that tracks the subtree weight and minimum value of each subtree and update these as you remove individual minima:

To initialize the tree: First, think of each element in the list as a one-element sublist with its minimum equal to its value. Then, while you have more than one sublist, group the subsequences in pairs, building a tree of subsequences. The length of a sequence is the sum of lengths of both its halves, and its minimum is equal to whichever minimum from both halves is lower.

To remove the minimum from a subsequence while tracking its index in the sequence:

- Decrease the length of the subsequence
- Remove the minimum from whichever half's minimum is equal to this subsequence minimum
- the new minimum is the lower of its halves' new minima
- The index of the minimum is equal to its index in its respective half, plus the length of the left half if the minimum was in the right half.
- The distance from one end is then equal to either the index or (length before removal - index - 1), whichever is lower.